# Replace character in a span with line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a one little thing for few hours and I don't know why nothing works for me.

The problem is I want to take every span with class "variant" and change its content in a way that every ";" semicolon will be replaced with a line break. I've been trying dozens of solutions and nothing works.

```
<span class="variant">Coin Wallet: Yes (+7,5 €); Business Card Holder: No; Monogram + 16,25 € (max. 10 symbols): </span>
```

I've tried solutions like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var text = $(".variant").val().replace(/\;/g, "<br>");
$(".variant").val(text);
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".variant").replaceText( /;/gi, "<br>" );
});
```

Comment: Show your effort, even incorrect code with html will suffice

Comment: You need to share the html mark up and the js you have tried

Comment: Give a brief pseudocode/idea how are you implementing this. Then we can look into what you're missing.

Comment: You should try using ,html() instead of .val().

Comment: @Bruno Works like a charm! THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span elements don't have values. So you can set or get their contents by using `html()` and also `text()`. The only elements that have values are input elements, where you would use `val()`.

```
<span class="variant">Coin Wallet: Yes (+7,5 €); Business Card Holder: No; Monogram + 16,25 € (max. 10 symbols): </span>
<button id="replace">Replace!</button>
```

Loop through all `<span>` elements with the `<class>` "variant" using the jQuery [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method and replace.

```
$("#replace").click(function(){
  $("span[class='variant']").each(function() {
  var text = $(".variant").html().replace(/\;/g, "<br>");
   $( this ).html(text);
  });
 });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/L5pprh0d/1/

Comment: Shouldn't this line: var text = $(".variant").html().replace(/\;/g, "<br>"); use this instead of .variant otherwise it will replace each instance with the first content it finds in the first .variant span.